# Pass session variable to more than one page in PHP

Tags: php, session

I am using this simple login script to make a simple panel:
https://github.com/panique/php-login-minimal

My problem is that I can not pass $_SESSION variables to more that one page. I want the user to see more that one page.

This is part of my code:

```
 // ... ask if we are logged in here:
if ($login->isUserLoggedIn() == true) {
    // the user is logged in. you can do whatever you want here.
    // for demonstration purposes, we simply show the "you are logged in" view.
    include("views/logged_in.php");
} else {
    // the user is not logged in. you can do whatever you want here.
    // for demonstration purposes, we simply show the "you are not logged in" view.
    include("views/not_logged_in.php");
}
```

Even if I include *example.php* it still doesn't work.

Comment: OT: I took a quick look into that simple package... and its dangerously teetering with its sql injection protection. It would not be considered safe to use unless you know *for certain* you do not fall within the bad edge cases. The author of that library really should update his code to using prepared statements.

Comment: On your other pages, to get at the $_SESSION variables, you would just need `session_start();` at the top of those pages. This requires users to have cookies on BTW.